# PHP Session Array not working when adding more than 2 items

Tags: php, arrays, session, shopping-cart

I want to add products to my array, but every time I add a product, it replaces the old one in the array.

When I add 2 things, it works fine:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 8 )
```

But when I try to add a third item or more, it replaces the second item in the array:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 10 )
```

Here is my code:

```
  session_start();

  if(isset($_POST['inCart']))
  {
       $id = $_POST['id'];

       if(!empty($_SESSION['cart']))
       {     
          $session = $_SESSION['cart'];
          $session[] = $id;

          print_r($session);
       }

       else
       {
          $_SESSION['cart'] = array($id); 
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see you forgot set SESSION with new data

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['cart']))
       {     
          $session = $_SESSION['cart'];
          $session[] = $id;

          $_SESSION['cart'] = $session;

          print_r($session);
       }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, was a stupid mistake of me.

I also shortened my code now I know my mistake

   session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['inWagen']))
    {
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      
      if(isset($_SESSION['winkelwagen']))
      {     
         $_SESSION['winkelwagen'][] = $id;
      }

      else
      {
         $_SESSION['winkelwagen'] = array($id); 
      }
    }